# ¿Cómo convertir una variable string a objeto Date en JS?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando convertir una variable string a un objeto Date, para realizar algunas acciones después de la conversión. El problema es que en navegadores como Chrome, Opera, Edge funciona, pero al probarlo en Firefox no funciona. Alguien sabe por que?

Este es mi código JS:

```
function muestraReloj () {
   fetch("http://localhost:82/Cons/reloj.php") 
   .then(response => response.text())
   .then(data => reloj.value = data); 

 var fechaYHoraAc = reloj.value;
 var fechaYHora = new Date(fechaYHoraAc);
 console.log(fechaYHora);
```

Este es mi código de reloj.php:

```
<?php 

date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
echo $s = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

?>
```

El resultado reloj.value me asegure de ver que es lo que contiene y obtengo 2021-09-19 09:00:00 y al convertirlo y hacer un console.log de fechaYHora me da como resultado fecha invalida. Esto solo me pasa en Firefox.

Comment: Lo probé en la consola de Firefox (92.0) asumiendo que `fechaYHoraAc = '2021-09-19 09:00:00'` y funciona correctamente.

Comment: Gracias por comentar, actualice mi respuesta, si imprimo  hago esto FechaYHoraAc = '2021-09-19 09:00:00' si funciona, pero si en lugar de la fecha la establezco lo establezco así : var fechaYHora = new Date(fechaYHoraAc); no funciona.

Comment: Asyncronia? Añade un `then(data => new Date(data).then(fechayHora => console.log(fechaYhora)`

Comment: No olvides usar el [estándar ISO 8601](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Fechas_y_horas_conjuntas)...

Comment: El código tal como está no te debería funcionar en ningún navegador, no solo en Firefox. Estás invocando una variable que aún no existe. Tienes que mover el `new Date(respuesta_asíncrona)` y lo que dependa de este adentro del callback.

Answer (score 1):

El formato de Firefox para date es:
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ
Por ejemplo:
"2021-09-19T09:00:00.000Z"

Aunque tengo entendido que lo corregía el propio navegador.
puedes probar este formato a ver si funciona. Suerte.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, tienes toda la razón. El problema es que al convertirlo la hora no la convertía, entonces se tuve que hacer un substrig para sacar cada uno de esos datos y convertirlos a objeto.